# Select non empty elements of list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

Given:

```
a = 'aaa'
b = ''
c = 'ccc'
d = ''
e = 'eee'

list = (a, b, c, d, e)
```

How can I get a string using all the non empty elements of the list ?

Desired output:

```
'aaa,ccc,eee'
```

Comment: ''.join(list).replace(' ',',')

Comment: Good work closing the question guys, now he has to read two other answers and combine them to achieve what he wants in a less-than-idiomatic fashion. **When did enforcing the rules become more important than teaching people?** I'm voting to reopen, there's a difference between keeping the site clean and a question witch hunt.

Comment: @slezica I dont think its about the rules in this case, more about what he is asking. there is a difference, but is it a witch hunt in this case?

Comment: `(a, b, c, d, e)` is a tuple, not a list. Lists are in `[]`.

Comment: I would suggest changing the title. Because the title question asks for combining non-empty list elements, whereas the body and the answers all talk about joining strings. What if `a` though `e` are lists or tuples, with `b` and `d` `=[]` or `=()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a generator expression:

```
",".join(string for string in lst if len(string) > 0)
```

The `",".join()` part is using the `join()` method of strings, which takes an iterable argument and outputs a new string that concatenates the items using `","` as delimiter.

The generator expression between parenthesis is being used to filter empty strings out of the list.

The original list doesn't change.

Comment: Note, you can also just use the condition `if string`, so `','.join(string for string in lst if string)` works the same and is slightly more concise.

Comment: "and this doesn't create a new in-memory list either" - no, [it totally does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9950), because `join` materializes the argument into a list so it can make two passes.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest thing you can do is

```
','.join(filter(None, mytuple))
```

(I renamed `list` to `mytuple` in oder to not shadow the builtin `list`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `generator-expression`:

```
','.join(s for s in list if s)
```

which `outputs`:

```
'aaa,ccc,eee'
```

---

**Why?**

This takes advantage of the fact that an `empty` `string` evaluates to `False`.

This can be seen clearer through some examples:

```
>>> if "a":
...     print("yes")
... 
yes
>>> if " ":
...     print("yes")
... 
yes
>>> if "":
...     print("yes")
... 
>>>
```

So the `generator` says: for each `string` in `list`, keep '*if* `string'` - i.e. if the `string` is not empty.

We then finally use the `str.join` method that will take each `string` in the `iterator` that is passed into it (here a `generator`) and concatenate them together with whatever the `str` is. So here we use a `','` as the `string` to get the desired result.

A little example of this:

```
>>> ','.join(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'])
'abc,def,ghi'
```

---

**As a side note, you shouldn't name your `variable` `list` as it overrides the built-in `list()` function:

```
>>> list((1, 2, 3))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list = 1
>>> list((1, 2, 3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too:

```
a = 'aaa'
b = ''
c = 'ccc'
d = ''
e = 'eee'
tup = (a, b, c, d, e)

res = ",".join(filter(lambda i: not i=='', tup))

print(res)
```

The output will be:

```
aaa,ccc,eee
```

It is also a good practice not to use `list` as a variable name, as it is a reserved keyword from Python.